# Make a "flat" JSON using Gson()

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I would like to make a "flat" JSON of a class.

Suppose I have class like the following:

```
public class Parcel {
private double area;
private int type;
private Address address;
}
```

and

```
public class Address {
private String street;
private int number;
private int flatNumber;
}
```

Is there any chance to make a JSON looking like this:

```
{
"area":0.0,
"type":1,
"Address.street":"street name",
"Address.number":22,
"Address.flatNumber":29
}
```

I don't need to deserialize JSON. I need to send it to the WS.

Comment: did you try something out ?

Comment: What is the need to do that? I mean, I don't understand specific use of it.

Comment: You can do it with some code(string manipulation). I don't think there is a library for formatting like this weird format.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to change how the webservice works, so that is why this weird format I need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to write a custom serializer, so that you have control over the json scheme you want to send.

```
private static class ParcelSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Parcel> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Parcel src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.addProperty("area", src.area);
        obj.addProperty("type", src.type);
        JsonObject addrObj = context.serialize(src.address, Address.class).getAsJsonObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : addrObj.entrySet()) {
            obj.add("Address."+e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Then you just need to register it into the `GsonBuilder`:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().registerTypeAdapter(Parcel.class, new ParcelSerializer()).create();
String json = gson.toJson(p, Parcel.class);
```

Given your example it outputs:

```
{
  "area": 0.0,
  "type": 1,
  "Address.street": "street name",
  "Address.number": 22,
  "Address.flatNumber": 29
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not expect complete solution :)

Comment: @rdkit I assumed this was a simplified example but if it was all your structure then it's cool :-)

Comment: First, it works :) and second I need to rebuild it a little to have all remaining fields of a Parcel serialized automatically. I think I need to use reflection.